# Unpivot in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have seen some of the examples we have for pivot and unpivot in mysql,where the rows and columns are changes accordingly, but i have a table like below
[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2yCG.png)

```
Month    Current            30 Days       30 - 60 Days 
Apr-13   1375159316       34511076         6423821 
May-13   71398540         5674629          4775687 
Jun-13   1314130060       27364660         9328588
```

and want it to create a new table like below
[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgG3Q.png)

```
Month            Apr-13         May-13          Jun-13
Current         1375159316    71398540       1314130060 
30 Days         34511076      5674629        27364660 
30 - 60 Days     6423821      4775687         9328588
```

So how can i do this using pivot or unpivot or what will be the best way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: what your tried update your query.

Comment: Those aren't comma-delimited values, are they?

Comment: No they are not comma seperated values...they are two different tables....with Month,Current,30Days and 30-60 Days as the columns of the first table, which needs to be converted as the 2nd table..